# Let $f,g:X\rightarrow S^n$ be maps satisfying $f(x) + g(x) \not= 0$ for all $x\in X$. Prove $f\simeq g$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was assigned this problem for homework. I am not exactly sure where to start with this proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: The condition means that f and g never send a point to opposite sides of the sphere. This means you can write down an explicit homotopy: first do it in Rn without the origin by having f(x) travel to g(x) along the line connecting them. Note that the condition means this line doesn't pass through the origin. Then you can turn this into a homotopy of maps to the sphere. Try n =1 first.

Answer (score 3):

Remark that for $t\in [0,1]$,  $tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)=0$ implies that $tf(x)=(1-t)g(x)=0$, since $\|f(x)\|=\|g(x)\|=1$, we deduce that $t=1-t$ and $t=1/2$ and $f(x)+g(x)=0$ impossible, so you can define Write $H(t,x)={{tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)}\over{\|tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)\|}}$

Comment: To prove something like this, I must find an explicit homotopy. Do you have any suggestions about how I might get better at thinking up these mappings?

Comment: $H(t,x)$ in the answer is such an homotopy.

Comment: The method for thinking up these mappings is to draw pictures until you understand geometrically what is happening, and then use your knowledge of analytic geometry to convert your pictures into formulas.